# Angular - Unit testing Subject()?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, testing, karma-runner

I have a Angular service that simply uses a Subject, but I am unsure of how to write unit tests for it.

I saw [this thread][1], but I didn't find it terribly helpful.

I have attempted to mock `next()` but I am more than a little lost.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should spy on `service.serviceMsg` and not `service`, because `next()` method appears to be on `serviceMsg` subject.

```
it('should catch what is emitted', () => {
    const nextSpy = spyOn(service.serviceMsg, 'next');
    service.confirm(ACTION);
    expect(nextSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

EDIT :

You should also change the way you are creating `service` instance. What you show in your code is applicable only for `component` instance creation

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [MessageService]
    });
    service = TestBed.get(MessageService); // get service instance
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
});
```

Comment: I see what you mean. Although I am getting the error: `Error: Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive MessageService.`

Comment: @trichetriche - Do you have any knowledge of this issue?

Comment: You cannot create `service` instance like `fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MessageService);
    service = fixture.componentInstance;`. That is applicable for component only. Instead you should be doing `service = TestBed.get(MessageService)`

Comment: Ah amazing! Thank you for your help @Amit :-)

Comment: @physicsboy if you want to notify me, it has to be on a question/answer I already commented on, otherwise I don't receive a notification !

Comment: @trichetriche - Whoops. Better just giving me your email XD

Answer (score -3):

Firstly you can just subscribe  to your `Subject` and inside expect some value and after that just execute method which will emit that:

```
it('should catch what is emitted', () => {
    service.serviceMsg.subscribe(msg => {
        expect(msg).toEqual(something);
    });
    service.confirm(value); // this should match what you expect above
});
```

Comment: By doing that you rely on the implementation of `Subject`, which is not what a unit test should do. You should instead mock it like he tried to do.

Comment: I believe it is not unit test since it includes things like creating module or injecting. It is true that it will rely on ``Subject`` implementation.